# How to include lib without '/'?

Tags: include, vtk

For example:

I installed libvtk-5.8.

And I try to include vtkAppendPolyData.h not vtk-5.8/vtkAppendPolyData.h.

Because the method include  is used in some libraries that I don't want to patch code by myself.

How to do that?

Thank you~

Comment: You need to setup your include paths for your compiler. Normally with vtk you are expected to use CMake to generate your project files or make files and it will handle the details of your include paths and linking for you. Without using CMake you need to do a lot of manual work.

Comment: You should NOT try to use VTK without CMake unless you REALLY know what you're doing. There are a huge number of include paths and libraries that would be required. Since it sounds like you installed a system package of VTK rather than build it yourself, are you using #include <vtkAppendPolyData.h> (versus #include "vtkAppendPolyData.h")?